# How to delete Android listview items using Contextual Action Mode

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, contextual-action-bar

I have succeeded in populating data from an `SQLite db` into a `listview` using `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Now I want to use `Contextual Action Mode` to delete some specific rows from listview and their equivalent SQLite data.

So far, I have been able to add Action Mode and make row selection accordingly.

However, I can't figure out how to remove selected rows from listview and delete them from SQLite db.

Help much appreciated!

Here is my  `main activity`:

```
public class FavBawords3 extends ListActivity {

private FavBaDbAdapter2 dbHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;
String DATABASE_FILE_PATH= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/FAVID";

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.fav_ba_main2); 

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bg_new);
      Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), myImage);         
      actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
      actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">" + "<b>" + getString(R.string.TextFavourite) + "</b"+ "</font>"));

    } else {

    }

  dbHelper = new FavBaDbAdapter2(this);
  dbHelper.open(); 

  db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH + File.separator + "favtemp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

  displayListView();

 }

 @Override
 protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
     getActionBar().setSubtitle("Long press to start selection");
 }

 public void myClickHandler(View v) 
 {
    //get the row the clicked button is in
     LinearLayout child = (LinearLayout) v.getParent().getParent(); 
     LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) child.getParent(); 

        TextView text=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.code);
        if (v.getId() == v.getId()) {


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    text.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (v.getId() == v.getId()) {
            int count = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
            if (!(count == 0)) {
                //text.setText("" + (--count));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        text.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

 }

private void displayListView() {

  Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllItems();

  // The desired columns to be bound
  String[] columns = new String[] {
    FavBaDbAdapter2.KEY_CODE,
    FavBaDbAdapter2.KEY_NAME,
    FavBaDbAdapter2.KEY_TIME,
  };

  // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
  int[] to = new int[] { 
    R.id.code,
    R.id.name,
    R.id.time,
  };

  // Simple cursor adapter and set it to display
  final SimpleCursorAdapter colours = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.fav_ba_grow2, cursor, columns, to, 0 );
  setListAdapter(colours);

  colours.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
          if (view.getId()==R.id.name)
            { 
              int incOrExpIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("content");
              int incOrExp = cursor.getInt(incOrExpIndex);

            switch(incOrExp) {
                case 0: 
                    TextView tv0 = (TextView)view;
                    //tv0.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                    tv0.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
                    tv0.setText(Utility.decodeContent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content"))));

                    break;
                case 1:   
                    TextView tv1 = (TextView)view;
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    tv1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("content")));
                    break;
              }
             return true;

        }
          if (view.getId()==R.id.code)
          { 
            int incOrExpIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("word");
            int incOrExp = cursor.getInt(incOrExpIndex);

          switch(incOrExp) {
              case 0: 
                  TextView tv0 = (TextView)view;
                  //tv0.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

                  //tv0.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word")));
                  tv0.setText(Utility.decodeContent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("word"))));

                  break;

            }
           return true;

      }

          return false;}  

    });

  ListView lvItems = getListView();  // Assign adapter to ListView   
  lvItems.setAdapter(colours); 
  lvItems.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
  lvItems.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new ModeCallback());

  lvItems.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          return true;
      }  

  });


  lvItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, 
     int position, long id) {
   // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
   Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

   String FavWord = Utility.encodeContent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("word")));


   }
  });


  colours.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
         public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
             return dbHelper.fetchItemsByName(constraint.toString());  
         }
     });

 }


    private class ModeCallback implements ListView.MultiChoiceModeListener {

        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.fav_view2, menu);
            mode.setTitle("Select Items");
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {


            return true;
        }

        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.share:
                getCheckedItems();
                mode.finish();
                break;
            default:


                Toast.makeText(FavBawords3.this, "Clicked " + item.getTitle(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private String getCheckedItems() {

            SparseBooleanArray checked = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                if(checked.valueAt(i) == true) {

                    String test = getListView().getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i)).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(FavBawords3.this, "Clicked " + test,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }

                }

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
        }

        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            final int checkedCount = getListView().getCheckedItemCount();

            switch (checkedCount) {
                case 0:
                    mode.setSubtitle(null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mode.setSubtitle("One item selected");
                    break;
                default:
                    mode.setSubtitle("" + checkedCount + " items selected");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    }
```

These are: 
    [DatabaseAdapter](http://pastebin.com/CRYTqpVK)
    [DatabaseItem](http://pastebin.com/cic0pZYh)

Comment: get the position you selected and remove the item from adapter. and do a simple query.

Comment: More details, pls. I have tried 
         SparseBooleanArray checked = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
         for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
             if(checked.valueAt(i) == true) {
              
              String test = getListView().getItemAtPosition(checked.keyAt(i)).toString();
              Toast.makeText(FavBawords3.this, "Clicked " + test,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); - but don't know what to do next.

Comment: do you want remove the selected items, you receiving in the `SparseBooleanArray checked = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();`. right?

Comment: I guess Yes, because that's the only thing I could be thinking of.